# shell command delete line in text file with specific text in line

Tags: linux, shell, command

In looking for a command to delete a line (or lines) from a text file that contain a certain string. 
For example
I have a text file as follows

```
Sat 21-12-2014,10.21,78%
Sat 21-12-2014,11.21,60%
Sun 22-12-2014,09.09,21%
```

I want to delete all lines that have "21-12-2014" in them. 
I'm not able to find a solution that works.

Comment: sed, grep, awk all do that. What did you try?

Comment: `grep -v 21-12-2014 filename.txt`? `awk '! /21-12-2014/' filename.txt`? `sed -e '/21-12-2014/d' < filename.txt`? Python or Perl are equally capable of doing this simply, and there's probably a number of other solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
sed -i.bak '/21-12-2014/d' *
```

#### A bit of explanations :

- `sed` : the main command line, put the mouse pointer on [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)
- `-i.bak` : replace the file *in place* and make a backup in a `.bak` file
- `//` is the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)
- `d` means: *delete*

Comment: Besides, that deletes the string, not the line. you need the `d` command.

Comment: Sputnick. How would I include an 'and' expressions. So I want to delete all lines  with 21-12-2014 AND 60%?

Comment: `sed -i.bak '/21-12-2014.*60%/d' *` maybe the time to learn regex and understand what involves ?

Answer (score 1):

According to **@twalberg** there is more three alternate solution for this question, which I'm explaining is as follows for future reader of this question for more versatile solutions:

With `grep` command

```
grep -v 21-12-2014 filename.txt
```

**explanations:**

`-v` is used to find non-matching lines

With `awk` command

```
awk '! /21-12-2014/' filename.txt
```

**explanations:**

`!` is denoting it will print all other lines that contain match of the string. It is not operator signify ignorance.

With `sed` command

```
sed -e '/21-12-2014/d' < filename.txt
```

**explanations:**

`-e` is signify scripted regex to be executed

`d` is denoting delete any match

`<` is redirecting the input file content to command